# i try to increment Assembly File version and Assembly info not found,

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration, version, continuous-deployment

Hie, 
I have an empty Api.NET core project. And I try to increment Assembly file version.
For this I use an extension update "assembly info".

like this:

[image: My Build Core]

I entered file version like this:

[image: My Version Numbers pattern]

I ever tried to enter this parameters: `$(Build.BuildNumber)` Or `$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion).$(BuildId)`

But my final result version did not set:

[image: Final Result]

I saw the doc of assembly info extension, but I don't find any assemblyinfo

Have you an idea about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution without this extension :
I use dotnet build and dotnet publish commands.
In my build step I add `/p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)` into arguements :

[image]

Idem for my publish step:

[image]